# How to send post requests using multi threading in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, post, python-requests

I'm trying to use multi threading to send post requests with tokens from a txt file.

I only managed to send GET requests,if i try to send post requests it results in a error.
I tried modifying the GET to POST but it gets an error.

I want to send post requests with tokens in them and verify for each token if they are true or false. (json response)

Here is the code:

```
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue
import requests

file_lines = open("tokens.txt", "r").readlines() # Gets the tokens from the txt file.
for line in file_lines: 
    param={
        "Token":line.replace('/n','')
    }


def make_request(url):
    """Makes a web request, prints the thread name, URL, and 
    response text.
    """
    resp = requests.get(url)
    with print_lock:
        print("Thread name: {}".format(threading.current_thread().name))
        print("Url: {}".format(url))
        print("Response code: {}\n".format(resp.text))

def manage_queue():
    """Manages the url_queue and calls the make request function"""
    while True:

        # Stores the URL and removes it from the queue so no 
        # other threads will use it. 
        current_url = url_queue.get()

        # Calls the make_request function
        make_request(current_url)

        # Tells the queue that the processing on the task is complete.
        url_queue.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Set the number of threads.
    number_of_threads = 5
    
    # Needed to safely print in mult-threaded programs.
    print_lock = threading.Lock()
    
    # Initializes the queue that all threads will pull from.
    url_queue = Queue()

    # The list of URLs that will go into the queue.
    urls = ["https://www.google.com"] * 30

    # Start the threads.
    for i in range(number_of_threads):

        # Send the threads to the function that manages the queue.
        t = threading.Thread(target=manage_queue)

        # Makes the thread a daemon so it exits when the program finishes.
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    
    start = time.time()

    # Puts the URLs in the queue
    for current_url in urls:
        url_queue.put(current_url)

    # Wait until all threads have finished before continuing the program.
    url_queue.join()

    print("Execution time = {0:.5f}".format(time.time() - start))
```

I want to send a post request for each token in the txt file.

Error i get when using replacing get with post:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Creative\Desktop\multithreading.py", line 40, in 
url_queue = Queue()
NameError: name 'Queue' is not defined
current_url = url_queue.post()
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'post'
File "C:\Users\Creative\Desktop\multithreading.py", line 22, in manage_queue

Also tried a solution using tornado and async but none of them with success.

Comment: Does a POST request work when you don’t use multithreading?

Comment: Yes it is working.

Comment: What is the error you get? Please edit the __full__ error message including traceback into your question as text.

Comment: So does it work if you set `number_of_threads` to 1? And 2?

Comment: Perhaps google doesn’t like getting multiple parallel POST requests - have you tried with a different url?

Comment: I usually get this error.     current_url = url_queue.post()
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'post' , And yes if try do post requests without threads it works fine.

Comment: Yes i did with other urls, but i get the same error when trying to do with post,it is working fine with get requests but when i try with post it is not working.

Comment: Please put the text of the error message with stack traceback into your question. The error is telling your that `url_queue` doesn’t have a method `post()`. Surely you should be doing something more like `requests.post(current_url)`?

Comment: I will try it  again with `requests.post(current_url)` this only worked for me when using only a thread,if you want i can send over the code with the single thread.

Comment: As the code in the question works, it would seem sensible to edit the code that *doesn’t* work into your question, along with the text of the error you get.

Comment: Do you know any ways to send post reqs using multi threads i still couldn't manage to find any.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to do post requests using multi threading.

If anyone sees an error or if you can do an improvement for my code feel free to do it :)

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import time

url_list = [
    "https://www.google.com/api/"
]
tokens = {'Token': '326729'}

def download_file(url):
    html = requests.post(url,stream=True, data=tokens)
    return html.content

start = time()

processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200) as executor:
    for url in url_list:
        processes.append(executor.submit(download_file, url))

for task in as_completed(processes):
    print(task.result())


print(f'Time taken: {time() - start}')
```